# How to delete macOS Installer boot

Tags: terminal, startup, software-update, error, secure-erase

I tried to install a macOS High Sierra update, but I got the error "An error occurred installing macOS" and thus I decided to erase the Installer.app and dmg on my drive. Now every time I close my Mac it shuts down and tries to boot from the macOS Installer boot, but because I erased the update I get the "No Symbol sign". I restart my mac and use the power key + Option to boot into my actual boot, but I don't seem to find someone who knows how to erase that boot, is there a way you can help me out?

Comment: when you opened the dmg file did you get a .pkg file or just an app?

Comment: just an app on my system

Comment: Have you tried erasing the file using AppCleaner or some app like that?  You may have some files left fro m you earlier attempt. But i guess if you deleted file you can't do this.

Comment: Correct, however I still got the problem I can not believe no one knows how to delete a boot....

Answer (score 1):

At the Startup Manager (accessed with holding alt/option at boot), with your macOS volume highlighted by the up arrow, hold down ctrl (which transforms the up arrow to a circular arrow) then choose the macOS volume. This will set this volume to be used as the startup disk in the future.

Comment: However I do have the macbook with the touchbar so I don't have volume arrow...

Comment: @Zenoheld By ‘volume’ I refer to a disk volume, like a partition. At the Startup Manager, there is an up arrow, hold ctrl to change the up arrow to a circular arrow, and then click on the button with the circular arrow (while the disk volume containing macOS is highlighted).

Comment: I see, I did that however my mac believes there is something to install and thus restarts closing all the work I was doing is really not a way to delete it?, btw I did follow what you said.